# How to group the green contour and the yellow contour?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, contour

I'm using `imcontour` in MATLAB to get the contour of some image. The resulting image is as follow. Is there any way that I can pick out the green contour together as a group, and the yellow contour together as a group?

[fig.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrxFZ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good news is that your data are already grouped. Assuming you have an image/matrix `I` and you are doing something like `imcontour(I, 2)`, you have just to use `[C, h] = imcontour(I, 2)`. 
`C` is a `ContourMatrix`, which contains (type `help clabel`) the "contour line definitions, returned as a two-row matrix. Each contour line in the plot has an associated definition. If there are a total of `N` contour lines in the plot, then the contour matrix consists of `N` definitions (`N=2` in your example):

```
C = [C(1) C(2)...C(k)...C(N)]
```

Each contour line definition follows this pattern:

```
C(k) = [level   x(1) x(2) ... x(numxy)
        numxy   y(1) y(2) ... y(numxy) ]
```

Comment: thank you, it works! But I got some trouble trying to store these contours. Since they are have different dimensions(i.e. some 2 by 12 some 2 by 20), how can I store them by writing a loop.

Comment: @yuan: you may store them in a cellarray (e.g. `contourGroups{k} = [ level x(1) y(1) ... x(numxy) y(numxy) ];`)

Comment: The idea of store matrix in cell is nice. Thank you for your help!